# feeding an array to numpy meshgrid

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

`meshgrid` seems to be coded in such a way that each dimension of the meshgrid has to be named individually (e.g. `x` and `y`)

`xv, yv = np.meshgrid(x, y)`

I am wondering if I can do the same just feeding an array which contains x and y, possibly setting some option of meshgrid to instruct it to use the array the way I need.

I want to do this because it makes life a lot easier when the number of dimensions onto which the meshgrid has to be build is either large or not known a priori.

So the problem is

```
np.meshgrid([1,2],[10,20])
```

gives

```
[array([[1, 2],
        [1, 2]]), array([[10, 10],
        [20, 20]])]
```

whereas I'd like to to something like

```
np.meshgrid([[1,2],[10,20]])
```

but this gives a useless 1D array.

I cannot find any helpful option in the [doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a case for *Unpacking Argument Lists*, and you use the [`*`-operator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) for this in python:

```
lst = [[1,2],[10,20]]
np.meshgrid(*lst)

#[array([[1, 2],
#        [1, 2]]), array([[10, 10],
#        [20, 20]])]
```